# "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key " empty key

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I'm getting this famous error

`[viewController setValue:forUndefinedKey:] this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .`

but the problem is that as you can tell above, the key is empty (aka `@""`).
if I put following code

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSLog(@"UndefinedKey is: %@", key);
}
```

in console I get

`UndefinedKey is:`

Putting a breakpoint and inspecting the `key` says it's empty.

Comment: Well empty is undefined isn't it?

Comment: check your outlets in the storyboard

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it is undefined, but where is it coming from? I've checked all the outlets there is no @"" outlet! or maybe I should search for something else?